# Changing granularity of OLAP cube

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

Is there any possibility to change granularity level in cube? I look for GROUP BY equivalent in MDX.

Now I have report based on SQL which I need move to the cube. The structure of it is something like this:

```
SELECT
   rank() over (partition by x order by y z) group_column
   ,a
   ,b
FROM abc
INNER JOIN def
...
INNER JOIN tuy
WHERE filter_statement
GROUP BY y, z
```

So, I do some joins with tables (dimensions) and based on this filtered table (abc), I use rank() function to count occurence of x column. After it I group whole query by group_column and calculate new measures:

```
SELECT
   group_column
   ,measure1
   ,measure2
FROM previous_table
GROUP BY group_column
```

After it, I get few rows depending on where conditions.

Is it possible to move it to the cube? I can't just create dimensions and fact table and join it, because I have to aggregate fact table (in this case abc) after joining others tables. After that I lose my keys (I have granularity of this grouped column, which vary according to joined tables), so I cannot create relations between tables.

My idea is to create MDX member, for each measure, which GROUP BY (MDX equivalent) fact table based on precalculated (in warehouse) column (group_column). In other words - I want to move second SQL query to cube.

I use SQL Server 2016. The biggest table have < 1M rows.